# Postgres: Encrypted User Function. Is it possible?

Tags: postgresql, cryptography

is it possible to create a function on PostgreSQL server, which routines can't be seen by any Postgres-user on the server?

The function gets some string as a parameter and outputs a boolean value. But nobody should know, how the calculation of the boolean value works.

Why do I need it: in the function's text is a private key. Maybe there is some other possibility to "hide" the private key or salt securely.

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but what happens if you create the function as one user and `grant execute` to another? Can the executor still see the text of the body of the function?

Comment: Not possible with core PostgreSQL. There is [third-party software](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/products/plpgsql_sec-encrypt-source-code/) for that.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: I also thought in this direction, but there is still a 'postgres' user, who is always able to overcome it, e.g. by granting himself the right to read the function's body.

Comment: I will ask the developers of the PL/PGSQL_SEC extension proposed by @LaurenzAlbe, how much the extension costs.

Many thanks for proposals so far :)

Comment: Well the postgres user is like root in Linux, it can do anything...